# Malloc and memory fragmentation

Tags: c, malloc, gnu

If I have many functions calling `malloc()` for small sizes (usually up to 500 bytes), then freeing when done. Will `malloc()` reunite adjacent blocks or is it going to keep splitting larger blocks and cause fragmentation?

For this scenario, is it better to use a buffer of enough size or call `malloc()` every time?

I'm interested in the GNU C Library, but answers regarding other implementations are also useful.

Comment: Do you have problems due to fragmentation? Do you expect to have it in the future? If the answer to those questions are "no" then don't worry about it. If, on the other hand, you make a program that is supposed to run for a long time (and by long I mean weeks or even months or years) without restarts, then you might want to implement your own heap allocation system (which can be base on `malloc`, allocate one giant "heap" and use that). There are plenty of free allocation algorithms if you search a little.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't have fragmentation problems nor do I expect to for what I'm doing now. I'm just interested in knowing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Is it likely to find a better implementation than the one in GCC, which gives less fragmentation? That would insinuate that the GCC implementation is poor somehow.

Comment: The `malloc` algorithm provided by GCC is indeed good, but it does fragment. What I meant was that if fragmentation might be a problem, then find an algorithm which can "defrag" the heap to avoid it completely. But in normal everyday use, even for many server-type programs, the standard `malloc` is fine.

Comment: I believe the GNU implementation merges the free blocks and can later use the merged blocks to allocate a larger memory. However, I am not sure if it is most efficient and best implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

malloc() is completely implementation dependent. You really cannot say 'officially' anything about it.

If you are really concerned about it, you can always write a datastructure that maintains a giant pool of 500 byte items, from which you take and giveback. so basically a specific malloc and free for that particular data type. These things help indeed a bit for systems with fixed sized objects, and a maximum number of them that don't change too much. for example on tree operations with fixed size nodes.

The fact that malloc() is generic and must account for different block sizes will always give it a disadvantage, compared to systems that don't have to reckon with that.